# Flask - Attach methods to specific tables?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Is it possible to attach a method to specific tables in flask so that the method runs before the data is inserted?

Example:

```
# Models.py
class Subscription(db.Model):
payment_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
notification_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

@staticmethod
def convert_date_utc(date):
    convert_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y")
    return convert_time.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

Instead of going through all the routes and wrapping the method around dates as per below, is it possible to automatically run these through the method on commit by attaching the method to their tables.

```
sub.payment_date = Subscription.convert_date_utc(formdata['payment_date'])
sub.notification_time = Subscription.convert_date_utc(formdata['notification_time'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a column of `DateTime`, you can make your own type.

Here's a quick example of how it'd work. It inherits off `DateTime` but you add an extra step when processing the value. You can have the `process_result_param` method too if you'd like to run some other code after fetching it from the database.

```
class CustomDateTime(TypeDecorator):

    impl = DateTime
    cache_ok = True

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
         convert_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y")
         return convert_time.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

Also look at this: [How to add methods to a column using SQLAlchemy TypeDecorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49652698/how-to-add-methods-to-a-column-using-sqlalchemy-typedecorator)